# This webpage has a redirect loop - rails locomotive cms engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms, redirect-loop

I have installed rails locomotive cms engine using this guide
http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/install-engine
 and everything worked fine but when I call the application on chrome browser with http://x.x.x.x:8080/locomotive I get the following error:

This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://x.x.x.x:8080/locomotive has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem...

cookies are already enabled

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check the logs why the redirect gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not knowing what the exact cause of your error, I had this same error for a bit and I resolved it by deleting that app engine, starting over and instead of at step one inputting:

> rails new myapp --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit --skip-javascript --skip-bundle

inputted:

> rails *3.2.16* new myapp --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit --skip-javascript --skip-bundle

[Source](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues/754)

I then followed the rest of the [steps](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/get-started/install-engine) and the redirect error disappeared and everything worked as expected.

Hopefully that helps!